# Separating entity persistence from logic

Tags: design

So, this is probably a repeated question, but I couldn't find a question which solve my questions.

At the beginning of the year, I started as a Junior Java Developer in a company that is in the market for 20+ years, so I deal with a lot of legacy code.

So far, so good, but something in architecture is bothering me. We have some Entities classes that are persisted using Hibernate and they only have fields and getter/setters, not any business logic.

Logic, therefore, is in a classes only for this purpose. The problem is that, in my opinion, this completely breaks OOP paradigm and make the code much harder to maintain and evolve.

Let me explain in pseudo-code:

In Layer Entity, I have something like this:

```
public class A {

        //constructors

        @Transient 
        private boolean canRead;

        @Transient
        private boolean canEdit;

        //getters and setter only

}
```

So, in the layer above, I have this, that perform some operation for endpoints.

```
public ALogic {

public boolean canRead(final A a) {
        Boolean permission = a.getCanRead();
        if( permission == null ) {
            this.verifyPermission(biAnalysis);
            permission = a.getCanRead();
        }

        return Boolean.TRUE.equals(permission);
} 

        private void verifyPermission(A a) {
              this.recordExists(a);
              if (...some condition) {
                  a.setCanRead(true);
                  a.setCanEdit(true);
              } else {
                 final Map<String, Boolean> permissions = this.getPermissions(a.getOid());
                 a.setCanRead(Boolean.TRUE.equals(permissions.get("read")));
                 a.setCanEdit(Boolean.TRUE.equals(permissions.get("edit")));
             }
      }
```

So this class (and similars, for different Entities) have a lot (like 800+ lines of code) that performs operations in theirs respectives entities. For me, this is only procedural programming, because I'm telling Entity how to do operations, don't asking.

Is this correct? Because is hard to find with some operation is already implemented, breaks encapsulation, the code gets more cluttered and gets more coupled because every logic operation, like save and delete, depends on another private method.

Is there a solution? Should I make some class that use class A as dependency like that or another solution?

```
public class B {

    public B (A a) {
         this a = a;
     }

    public canEdit() {
        //make operations like before in Logic class
 }
```

Where I can learn more about this to improve our product (some canonical books``) and my skills?

Comment: You might want to search for Anemic vs Rich domain model

Comment: I'm still trying to find the question here. You say "is this correct?" and "is there a solution?" What problems are you having with this code? Can you clarify your question?